# Bash Regex Matching digits

Tags: regex, bash

I am try to match only the digits from a text file that is in this format:

```
> 1234
```

I'm running thru the file with a loop. Every line store in `$i`

```
$i | grep "\d{4}"
```

Output looks like this:

```
>
1234
>
5678
```

Why is it still outputing the `>`? I want to remove those.

Comment: `$i` at the start of the line will try to run a command with its value, e.g. a command called `1234`.  I'm also confused about "what you are doing wrong."  Your output doesn't look wrong to me...

Comment: Do you want to show digits only?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean why is it outputing the `>`. I'm trying to get rid of those.

Comment: Did you expect grep to extract only the number? Grep will display the entire line containing a match. Maybe you want to use sed instead? (I'm deleting my answer since it didn't address the question you meant to ask.)

Comment: @William "Grep will display the entire line containing a match" not necessarily

Comment: Yeah, I spoke too soon. (Back in my day we didn't have --only-matching, and we liked it that way!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man grep`

> ```
>    -o, --only-matching
>           Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a
>           separate output line.
> ```

Try `grep -o ....`

Test:

```
i="> 1234"
$ echo "$i"
> 1234
$ echo "$i" | grep -oP "\d{4}"
1234
```

Comment: Note to self, check manpages... Obviously things have changed since Solaris 7's grep :-)